# CSRF verification failure when trying to upload an image from django-ckeditor on staging server

Tags: django, django-admin, csrf, http-status-code-403, django-ckeditor

Django-ckeditor has an option to insert and upload images directly from the editor.  This works on local/development machines, but on remote servers Django throws a 403 error, CSRF verification failed.  This happens in the admin backend, and I am having no other similar problems.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because of `url(r'^sys/cke/', include('ckeditor.urls'))` was included to urlpatterns *after* less restrictive pattern (namely, `url(r'^', include('cms.urls'))`).

Thus, when reverse url resolver was used to build absolute url for `ckeditor_upload` it worked properly, but when url resolver was to find proper view for request, the request went not to the ckeditor's view with @csrf_exempt, but to view with first matched pattern. The confusion was because the 403 Forbidden error message has no trace of the view being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is still open.

https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor/issues/84

Better to exempt the csrf verification.

Comment: I just looked in views.py in ckeditor, and the csrf_exempt decorator was already applied to the upload() view.  Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: Check ur settings middleware and try commenting your csrf middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved it, but I got the same problem. The issue was related to the django version. So you need to add this to your `urls.py`:

```
if django.VERSION >= (1, 8):
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('libs.ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]
else:
from django.conf.urls import patterns

admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls', namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('libs.ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
)
```